# SSIS Multiple Hash causing error on server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have installed SSIS Multiple Hash on my machine, and I am using it to build SSIS packages.

Once deployed I get the following error message when I execute:

```
The component metadata for "Multiple Hash, clsid {33D831DE-5DCF-48F0-B431-4D327B9E785D}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.

The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "http://ssismhash.codeplex.com/".
```

Any ideas?
I am using:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 for development

The ssis pakcage is deployed on:

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but in case someone else has the same problem:

Check under Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features on the server where you want to run the package that MultipleHash component is installed:
[image: Install infos]

If not then install it ([MultipleHash Download](https://ssismhash.codeplex.com/releases/view/125224)). Once that has been done you can validate your package if you use the Package Deployment Model. To do this go to the package and right-click and choose validate. Once this is successfull you should be fine.